# How to Fetch image from specified PATH or Document Directory using NSBundle

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, nsbundle

I have done a lot of research to find  the difference between the working of the codes below .
As im trying to fetch the image from the Document Directory that can be specified by PATH using NSBundle and show  it in ImageView.

TYPE 1:
This code is working fine and able to retrieve the image and display :

```
NSString *inputPath= @"/Users/abc/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/ADD46F96-333A-46BF-8291-FABD1BD7C389/Documents/colour.png";
NSString *jjj=[inputPath pathExtension];
NSString *hhhhh=[[inputPath lastPathComponent]stringByDeletingPathExtension];
NSString *bivivik=[inputPath stringByDeletingLastPathComponent];
NSString *imagePATH=[NSBundle pathForResource:hhhhh ofType:jjj inDirectory:bivivik];
theImage=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePATH];
mImageDisplayView.image=theImage;
```

TYPE 2:
But if i try as below code .Not fetching the image and showing null value

```
NSString* imagepath = [[NSBundle bundleWithPath:@"/Users/abc/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/ADD46F96-333A-46BF-8291-FABD1BD7C389/Documents/colour.png"]bundlePath];
theImage=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagepath];
mImageDisplayView.image=theImage;
```

What is the wrong with my TYPE 2 code .Is there any other way which i can fetch the image as im  trying in TYPE 2 method .please help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though the code above works in one instance, both the code snippets are wrong because they will fail to read the file on device. Reason is, you are using the absolute path from your MAC which simulator is able to find, however will not exist on device.

Use `[NSBundle mainBundle]` to read file from application bundle,

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"imageName" ofType:@"png"];
```

For reading file from documents directory of your application use this code snippet,

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *filePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Myfile.png"];
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

---

**EDIT**

If you have a separate bundle which contains image files then to read from that bundle use this snippet. Assuming that this bundle is in documents directory,

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *bundlePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyBundle.bundle"];
NSBundle *myBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:bundlePath];
NSString* imagePath = [myBundle pathForResource:@"MyImage" ofType:@"png"];
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: your answer is accepted . What if i need to access the image using NSBundle.  cau i use filePath like this             **NSString* imagepath = [[NSBundle bundleWithPath:filePath]bundlePath];**        Will it Works?

Comment: @lokesh Ignore my previous comment. The above API is not used for getting file in the application bundle. It is used to get path to a .bundle file.

Comment: Are you reading image files from a separate bundle other than `mainBundle`?

Comment: yes i need to read image from document directory using bundle

Comment: @lokesh If I am getting this correct, you want to read file from a bundle which is stored in Documents directory?